# How to use classes/dataclasses for structured data in python

Tags: python, structured-data

I have some data that I need to structurize, what I have now is below:

```
class Data1:
    name: str = ""
    file: str = ""

    class Data2:
        name: str = ""
        minLv: int = 1
        maxLv: int = minLv + 1
        Layer: int = 0
```

What kind of data will I have:
Data1 will have many lines of some data with parameters **name** and **file**, also **Data1** will have another structured *data* inside it, that can be more than one: e.g.: **Data1** will have 2+ "rows" of **Data2**.

I know it could be like JSON, but I need to have it as a class and inherit from that base class.

For better understanding, following code is what I need but with usage of classes:

```
data = {data1: {
        name: "name",
        file: "file",
        data2_0: {name: "name", minLv: 0 ...}
        data2_1: {name: "name", minLv: 0 ...}
        }
        data2: {
        name: "name",
        file: "file",
        data2_0: {name: "name", minLv: 0 ...}
        data2_1: {name: "name", minLv: 0 ...}
        data2_2: {name: "name", minLv: 0 ...}
        }
        ...}
```

Is there any better solution?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by creating classes for this? Instead of presenting the solution, try presenting the problem so we can understand how to help.